# How to enable ipython autocomplete commands based on history

Tags: python, macos, autocomplete, ipython

A friend somehow has enabled this nice feature.

I have a macbook pro as well but have not managed to make this work.

Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: I use LInux and it works for me at the beginning - in `ipython` and [bpython](https://www.bpython-interpreter.org/) - but as I know `ipython` uses module [python-prompt-toolkit](https://github.com/prompt-toolkit/python-prompt-toolkit) and maybe it has some option which you have to activate on Mac. I'm not sure but it may need C/C++ library `readline`

Comment: BTW: maybe problem can make terminal if it doesn't handle special codes to move coursor. Or maybe it can't write history in file and later it can't read in.

Comment: try Ctrl + P, works for me on zsh shell